# Ошибка в telebot

Tags: python, бот

Пытаюсь написать бота с помощью библиотеки Telebot но постоянно одна и таже ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
"C:/Users/User/Desktop/programir/python/bot/tg_1/main.py", line 6, in <module>
@bot.message_handlers(commands="start")
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

вот код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('не хочу полить токен')


@bot.message_handlers(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
send_mess = f"<b>Привет {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}</b>!\nКакое направление тебя интересует?"
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess, parse_mode='html')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: У вас в ошибке commands не список, а в коде список. Это норм?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте это: @bot.message_handler(commands=["start"]) (я поменял handlers на handler).